# Android onFling velocity

Tags: android

I'm wondering if the velocity of the fling event is screen size agnostic, or should I do adaptation according to screen size.

Will my exact same swipe in two different devices will produce the same velocity parameter on the fling event?

Comment: velocity is computed using VelocityTracker, see computeCurrentVelocity(), GestureDetector uses units == 1000

Comment: I think it may be different depending on the different sensitivity of accelerometer and touch screen. does it matter? what do you want to do with velocity?